# how to let js know about newly created html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am creating new html element with js.

```
$('#write_comment').on('click',function(){
  $(this).html('<textarea> </textarea><button onclick="test()">save</button>');
});

function test(){
 alert('testme');
}
```

but after these `textarea` and `button` were created, if i click on `save`, nothing happens.

is there any jquery function where i can say. `(newly_created_element).find(js_function)` ?

that or something with same functionality would be nice to have.

please help.

Comment: That should work, http://jsfiddle.net/QGGhW/

Comment: @Musa, thanks. i had to put the js function outside of ``$(function(){ })``

Comment: @Musa, why i cannot click and write anything inside of that textarea?? interesting

Comment: @Musa, it is throwing me out of textarea if i try to write inside

Comment: You have to take off the click handler on the div http://jsfiddle.net/QGGhW/1

Comment: @Musa, thanks. learn new thing :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#write_comment').on('click',function(){
  $(this).html('<textarea> </textarea><button id="test">save</button>');
});

$('body').delegate('#test','click',function(){
 alert('testme');
});
```

Using class

```
$('#write_comment').on('click',function(){
      $(this).html('<textarea> </textarea><button class="test">save</button>');
    });

    $('body').delegate('.test','click',function(){
     alert('testme');
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Create the button seperately:

```
$('#write_comment').on('click',function(){
  var myButton = $('<button>save</button>').click(function() {
    test();
  });
  $(this).html('<textarea></textarea>').append(myButton);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#write_comment').on('click',function(){
  $(this).html('<textarea> </textarea><button class="NewlyAdded">save</button>');
});
```

`$(document).on` behaves like `.live()` or `delegate()` in many ways. And will **work for elements that are added later**.

```
$(document).on('click','#write_comment button.newlyAdded',function()
{
  alert('testme');
});
```